# Display the result after substracting elements of a vector in TASM

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

I have this code to get the result I want but I cannot display it. I am new in TASM so I don't know how to work with. I looked over for some tutorials to show up the result but nothing found. Please help.

```
.model small
.286
.stack 100h

.data

vector  db 8,9,5,4,5,6,7     
n       db 7             ; dimensiunea vectorului
scadere db ' ','$'       ; suma elementelor

.code
    mov AX,@data 
    mov DS,AX

    xor SI,SI
    xor CX,CX            ; ne asiguram ca CX are valoarea 0

    mov CL,n             ; copiem in CL dimensiunea vectorului

repeat:                  ; definim eticheta   
    mov AL,vector[SI]
    sub scadere,AL
    inc SI      ; marim valoarea din SI cu 1 pentru a trece la elementul urmator 
    loop repeat ; salt la eticheta cat timp CX diferit de 0

    mov AX,4c00h
    int 21h

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not outputting the result.

Try

```asm
.model small
.286
.stack 100h

.data

vector  db 8,9,5,4,5,6,7     
n       db 7             ; dimensiunea vectorului
scadere db 'z',13,10,'$'       ; suma elementelor+CR+LF

.code
    mov AX,@data 
    mov DS,AX

    xor SI,SI
    xor CX,CX            ; ne asiguram ca CX are valoarea 0

    mov CL,n             ; copiem in CL dimensiunea vectorului

repeat:                  ; definim eticheta   
    mov AL,vector[SI]
    sub scadere,AL
    inc SI      ; marim valoarea din SI cu 1 pentru a trece la elementul urmator 
    MOV DX,OFFSET SCADERE       ;^message
    MOV AH,9             ;Dos function 9 = output until '$'
    INT 21H              ;execute DOS function
    loop repeat ; salt la eticheta cat timp CX diferit de 0

    MOV DX,OFFSET SCADERE       ;^message
    MOV AH,9             ;Dos function 9 = output until '$'
    INT 21H              ;execute DOS function
    mov AX,4c00h
    int 21h

end
```

This should show you the way.

There's a useful list of [DOS functions here.](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm)

I've changed `scadere` to start at `'z'` because you are subtracting hence you should display

'z' (7A) - 8 = `'r'` (72)
'r' (72) - 9 = `'i'` (69)
'i' (69) - 5 = `'d'` (64)
'd' (64) - 4 = `''`  (60)...

adding the 13,10 into `scadere` should produce a newline.

Comment: Thank you for help. I tested the code you rewrote, but it displays characters, not a number. How can I fix that ?